# SSRS how to send same report to different people but filter data by location

Tags: reporting-services

I would like to send SSRS report to users in different locations. It would be ideal to make one schedule with the Reporting Manager. Can SSRS filter the same report so that person A at Location 1 only sees their location information while person B and location 2 sees only their information? What if the attached files are excel?

We might dynamically add new locations, and I prefer to avoid making the same copy of the same report with a different parameter.

SAP Business Objects uses Profiles. I am looking for the same functionality with SSAS.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with subscriptions. You can set up a separate subscription for each person with the appropriate parameter value. This will send them each a copy of their report and you can have it be an Excel attachment. The specific steps vary based on if you're using SSRS in native or integrated mode, but you should be able to find examples on how to do this.

If you get into a more complicated scenario, the data-driven subscriptions offer even more flexibility. For example, you can have a list of recipients and parameter values in a table that drives the subscription.

Comment: Thanks Steve, so if one location has 25 users, how can I group the users together?

Comment: With a regular subscription you can separate all the email addresses with semicolons.

Comment: So the users and/or email addresses must be hard-coded and maintained?

Comment: Again, you can either hard code them in the subscription settings or use the data-driven option to pull them from a table. But yeah, they have to be stored and maintained somewhere.